# How to use ostream_iterator<> for a generic container at compile time?

Tags: c++, stl

I would like to use copy() to print out the content of a container of type T. I tried:

```
template<typename T>
void print_con( const T& con, const string& sep = ", ", const string& ms = "" ) {
 cout << ms << endl;
 copy( con.begin(), con.end(), ostream_iterator<?>( cout, sep ) ); 
}
```

What should I replace ? with?

Thanks,
Chan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look up the type of a container as the type

```
typename T::value_type
```

In this case, I believe what you want is

```
copy( con.begin(), con.end(), ostream_iterator<typename T::value_type>( cout, sep.c_str() ) );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. However, I actually tried your method. But it did not compile. I'm using VS 2010 C++

Comment: Hmmm... what error did you get?  I'm wondering if the problem is that the delimiter needs to be a raw C-style string, and so you might want to replace sep with sep.c_str().

Comment: Sorry, you're right! My bad! Sorry I should read the error message carefully.